# How to correctly map FHIR JSON Schema to PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jsonschema, jetbrains-ide, hl7-fhir

I have downloaded the official JSON Schema from [FHIR website](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html).
I tried to map it in PyCharm using [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/json.html#ws_json_schema_add_custom) but before applying my changes I get this error message :

```
Warning
JSON Schema not found or contains error in 'fhir.schema.json': Cannot load code model for JSON Schema file 'fhir.schema.json'
```

When using a JSON Schema [online validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/), I can see 147 errors in the file.
Some examples:

```
Found 147 error(s)

Message:
    JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'.
Schema path:
    http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/4.0#/oneOf

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: prescriber, patient, lensSpecification, resourceType.
Schema path:
    http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/4.0#/definitions/VisionPrescription/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: resourceType.
Schema path:
    http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/4.0#/definitions/VerificationResult/required

Message:
    Required properties are missing from object: resourceType.
Schema path:
    http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/4.0#/definitions/ValueSet/required
```

When I try to follow these links, they doesn't exist (404 Error).

What can I do to successfully apply the FHIR JSON Schema ? Where can I find a valid Schema ?

Comment: Those links are identifiers to specific locations in the JSON Schema itself, that you linked to at the FHIR website. Identification URIs do not actually have to be network-resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have PyCharm installed, but I've done some checking on the [provided JSON schema](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/fhir.schema.json.zip) and it worked on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ against the [examples](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/examples-json.zip) also provided by the FHIR website. See [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/hk5VF8SN) for an example.